# React Native - UseState, number-pad not working

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state, react-native-textinput

Here is my code -

```
const StartGameScreen = props => {
const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState('');

const numberInputHandler = inputText => {
  setEnteredValue(inputText);
};

const resetInputHandler = () => {
  setEnteredValue('');
};

return (
  <View>
    <TextInput
      blurOnSubmit
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      maxLength={2}
      onChangeText={numberInputHandler}
      value={enteredValue}
    />
    <View style={styles.button}>
      <Button title="Reset" onPress={resetInputHandler}/>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

I am having a couple of issues with the above code.

1. I am calling `numberInputHandler` function onChangeText, but the value is not updated. Similary, onPress of Reset button I am calling another function "resetInputHandler", it's not working too.
2. `keyboardType="number-pad"` is not working. I am able to see the normal keyboard in both iPhone and android simulator.

Would you please help to resolve the above issues?

Comment: your code is totally correct, all is working https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/input-issue. Maybe you have a cache issue just rerun the project.

Comment: Hey, yes - it worked perfectly fine after I rerun the project. Thanks for your reply :)